# HTML: raised letters (not superscript) as in McSurname

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

What's the cleanest way to cause a letter to be correctly raised to a **central** vertical position in relation to the rest of the text, as is conventional for certain surnames?

Good:

```
|\/|
|  | C
|  |
```

Bad (superscript):

```
|\/| C
|  |
|  |
```

Very bad: McSurname

I'm told this is easy to achieve by "simply changing a font," but a Unicode-based solution would be best for database reasons, or failing that something involving `span` and CSS...

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me.

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  }
.central-vertical-letter {
      font-size: 0.5em;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0.25em;
    }
```

```html
M<span class="central-vertical-letter">c</span>ewen
```